# name.sum() returns individual records rather than sum of records in python

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So I am a newbie learning python. And basically all I'm doing is just following the documentation and trying it for myself similarly. I have created a DataFrame with name and Births as columns and have used random seed to fill it up. But when I try to group it by name and tries to return the sum value of unique names, it just gives me the all the random numbers associated with it instead of giving me the total sum of it.

This is what my output looks like:

```
                                                    Births
Names                                                     
Erdogan  [188][180][172][56][192][74][199][76][103][144...
Jamal    [97][191][176][65][58][163][164][81][157][102]...
Mehdi    [160][151][175][80][186][164][134][180][70][66...
Yassir   [68][76][154][126][77][52][142][60][124][71][5...
```

This was my code:

```
name = df.groupby('Names')
df = name.sum()
print(df)
```

Comment: How did you create the original values?

Answer (score 0):

check your column types as below

```
df.dtypes
```

if datatype of `Births` is object, then convert into `int` as follows

```
df['Birth'] = df['Birth'].astype(int)
```

Now do the grouping and sum

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I am getting another error for that. ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '[188][180][172][56][192][74][199][76][103][144][118][192][114][57][78][90][131][59][188][61][52][183]'

Comment: How you are creating dataframe ? Can you provide the sample code to create your dataframe ?

Comment: random_births = [random.randint(low=50, high=200) for i in range(100)] This is how I created my list. And when I checked with isinstance(random_births, int) its returning false. and when i check with object it shows True. So I think Its being created as object.

Comment: This is how I created the dataframe
 df = pd.DataFrame(data = combined, columns=['Names', 'Births'])

Comment: please provide the data assigned to `combined`

Comment: combined = list(zip(random_names, random_births))

Answer (score 0):

I tried to guess what's your original DataFrame, and manage to get a similar result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','d','a','d'],'Births':['[188]','[180]','[172]','[56]']})
print(df.groupby('name').sum())
# then the result is:
#           Births
# name            
# a     [188][172]
# d      [180][56]
```

The problem is the type of column 'Births' is not correct, you need to map `'[186]'` to `186`, then you can get the desired result.

```py
df['Births'] = df['Births'].apply(lambda x: int(x[1:-1]))
print(df.groupby('name').sum())
#       Births
# name        
# a        360
# d        236
```

Comment: I am getting an error. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '188][180][172][56][192][74][199][76][103][144][118][192][114][57][78][90][131][59][188][61][52][183'

Comment: @zuestech it's a little bit tricky since you name the result DataFrame as df, which is the same name of your original DataFrame. Could you please try different names and make the changes to the original DataFrame? Or maybe you could show us what's your original DataFrame looks like